# Change icon of stand alone application, (AppImage)

Tags: permissions, icons

Ubuntu 19.04 is what I'm working with. I am trying to determine the best way to change an icon for this stand alone program, https://www.balena.io/etcher/?ref=etcher_footer

I tried copying program file to the desktop, opening the properties dialog box,clicking icon, and selecting new one. The icon changes in the properties dialog box, but not on the actual program file.

The permisions tab in properties shows that the file is owned by "root", and in the group "root". Then I tried opening nautilus as root, and changing "user" and "group" in properties/permissions. Still no change.

It's probably something simple, but I'm just spinning my wheels here. Any help would be great.

@Jim Using info on this site, https://itsfoss.com/use-appimage-linux/ I was able to integrate the appimage into Applications menu, though there still remained the problem of changing is icon, after installing .deb files from gitHub repository you posted your solution worked.

Apparently the AppImage icon issue has been going on for some time. https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/346

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is assuming you installed etcher from their repository or `.deb` files.

1. Open up terminal
2. Navigate to Ubuntu's application global dir.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/applications
   ```
3. Edit the Etcher's desktop entry.

   ```
   sudo gedit balena-etcher-electron.desktop
   ```
4. Change `Icon=` value to your image file location. Mine was in `~/Downloads` folder so put it like this.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=balenaEtcher
   Comment=Flash OS images to SD cards and USB drives, safely and easily.
   Exec="/opt/balenaEtcher/balena-etcher-electron" %U
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=/home/user/Downloads/GitLab_Logo.svg.png
   StartupWMClass=balenaEtcher
   Categories=Utility;
   ```
5. Save and exit to apply changes.
6. Run `sudo updatedb` to update database.
7. The icon will changes then.

From

[image]

To

[image]

Comment: Actually I downloaded the program from their website, but I will try it the way you said.

Comment: I downloaded it via `.deb` file from this link [balena-etcher-electron_1.5.33_amd64.deb](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.5.33/balena-etcher-electron_1.5.33_amd64.deb), however if you uses repo as this https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#installers instruct, then this should work too.

Comment: I didn't see it in synaptic, but searching for an etcher repository I ran accross this site, that described how to install an appimage in Linux. Sure enough the etcher file for Linux from  is an appimage. It's like an .exe; one file.

Comment: You have to add the repository first in order to install it in synaptic, etcher doesn't exist on default repository, instead it have it own third party repository.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my question.I actually never heard of an appimage, but this site, https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/um18-04-3-welcome-software-boutique-etcher-repository-fail/19296 describes how it can be installed. It now shows up in the program list.

Comment: I think I just found it on gitHub.  https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Probably you talking about desktop integration of AppImage file, weird but I never got one while installing Etcher.

Comment: @joeRag Yes I do mean that, that's the link I posted to you earlier.

Comment: The appimage is  from https://www.balena.io/etcher/?ref=etcher_footer and it's v1.5.33. the version on gitHub is v1.5.19

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93421/discussion-between-jim-and-joerag).

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution would be.
If you used appimagelauncher, by default the desktop file is added at

> ~/.local/share/applications/<filename_with_appname>.desktop

You can just change the 'Icon' value of the file to "new_icon path". This will update the icon shown in app launcher, finder.